# How to do pattern matching for abstract data type in OCaml?

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I have a set T, which have elements of the form int*< Abstract>*int.

I want to find a element of this set which is of the form, say 4*< Abstract>*5.

When i try to use

```
match T with 
|(4,_,5) -> Printf.printf "yes"
|(_,_,_) -> Printf.printf "no"
```

I am getting an error which says "Error: This expression has type transitionSet but an expression was expected of type loc * 'a * loc   "

How to find an element in the set?

Comment: You seem to be matching the whole set T where you want to match only one of its elements.

Comment: @Sheeft Yeah. Is there other way than making a list from T and then checking this for each element in list?

Answer (score 2):

Set is abstract therefore no way to pattern match itself.  Within OCaml's standard library Set module, what you can do is to `filter` the set then check it `is_empty` or not:

```
Set.(is_empty @@ filter p t)
```

where `p` is your predicate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your set module is called `TSet` and you are using OCaml standard library sets. I'm also assuming your set isn't really called `T`, since that is not a valid name for OCaml variables.

If you only care about a yes/no answer for whether a single matching value exists, you can do:

```
let result =
  TSet.exists
    (function
    | 4, _, 5 -> true
    | _       -> false)
    t in
if result then print_endline "yes" else print_endline "no"
```

In general, whatever your predicate is, you can do

```
TSet.exists p t
```

---

If you want more than a yes/no answer, and want to be able to perform arbitrary computations in the case branches on all the matching values in the set, you will have to use `fold` or `iter` with pattern matching. For example, if you want to add all the first integers together, but only when the last integer is 5:

```
TSet.fold
  (fun element accumulator ->
    match element with
    | x, _, 5 -> x + accumulator
    | _       -> accumulator)
  t 0
```

---

If you want to perform the computation only on the first matching element, you can short-circuit evaluation with an exception. For example:

```
exception Found of int

try
  TSet.iter
    (function
    | x, _, 5 -> raise_notrace (Found x)
    | _       -> ())
    t;
  None
with Found x -> Some x
```

This last one is awkward to type over and over. You can write a polymorphic function to solve the problem of short-circuiting pattern-matching search for yourself by using a reference and the built-in `Exit` exception. I'll leave that as an exercise.

It's a good idea to use `raise_notrace` since this exception is being used for normal flow control. If your program is one day compiled with stack traces enabled, `raise_notrace` will omit the stack trace when throwing the exception, which could make your program faster if your function is called often.

For your reference, http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Set.S.html